# Querying related records to xml field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, querying

I have to query a huge database. For every row, containing above hundred of fields, there are related records in three reated tables. Joining them will produce recordset multiplied tens of times (depending on related records count). I thought about combining fields from related tables to a single xml field.

For example:
Table1 (main table):

```
Id        Field1        Field2    ...more fields go here
1         Value1        Value2
2         Value3        Value4
```

Table2 (one of the related tables)

```
Id        ParentId      Field3        Field4
1         1             Value5        Value6
2         1             Value7        Value8
3         2             Value9        Value10
```

I would like to get a following result:

```
Id        Field1       Field2      XmlField1
1         Value1       Value2      XmlValue1
2         Value3       Value4      XmlValue2
```

Where XmlValue1 is as follows

```
<RelatedRecords>
   <RelatedRecord>
       <Field3>
           Value5
       </Field3>
       <Field4>
           Value6
       </Field4>
   </RelatedRecord>
   <RelatedRecord>
       <Field3>
           Value7
       </Field3>
       <Field4>
           Value8
       </Field4>
   </RelatedRecord>
</RelatedRecords>
```

And XmlValue2 is as follows

```
<RelatedRecords>
   <RelatedRecord>
       <Field3>
           Value
       </Field3>
       <Field4>
           Value10
       </Field4>
   </RelatedRecord>
</RelatedRecords>
```

How to get the desired output?

Comment: I would try to create a view and export these result as XML... but I would bet some other would try a different way. Please consider that we are here to help with errors or when you are stuck somewhere, and not to build a solution for you. Show us what you tried so far and why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by myself. Providing the desired solution for others:

```
SELECT Id, 
       Field1,
       Field2,
       (
       SELECT Field3, Field4
       FROM Table2
       WHERE Table1.Id = Table2.ParentId
       FOR XML PATH('RelatedRecord'), ROOT('RelatedRecords')
       ) XmlField1
FROM Table1
```